# Alert Bootstrap with Cookie

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cookies

i tried to use the alert from bootstrap to take a cookie notification.
I used the following code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" </script>

<script src="src/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function( $ ){

// Check if alert has been closed
if( $.cookie('alert-box') === 'closed' ){

    $('.alert').hide();

}

 // Grab your button (based on your posted html)
$('.close').click(function( e ){

    // Do not perform default action when button is clicked
    e.preventDefault();

    /* If you just want the cookie for a session don't provide an expires
     Set the path as root, so the cookie will be valid across the whole site     */
    $.cookie('alert-box', 'closed', { expire 7, path: '/' });

});

});
</script>

<!-- Body Markup -->
<div class="alert alert-info fade in">            
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        <strong> ALERT BODY</strong>
</div>
```

The fiddle link is:
http://jsfiddle.net/Nighteyes/fy0w1vLc/

Now i want that a cookie is set after push the close button. The cookie expire after 7 days.

Can anyone help me please?

Nighteyes

Answer (score 2):

For future readers using **Bootstrap 4**, the Toast component can now be used to create a cookie consent banner. Here's a working example:

https://codeply.com/p/azCmarhM9X

HTML:

```
<div class="fixed-bottom p-4">
    <div class="toast bg-dark text-white w-100 mw-100" role="alert" data-autohide="false">
        <div class="toast-body p-4 d-flex flex-column">
            <h4>Cookie Warning</h4>
            <p>
            This website stores data such as cookies to enable site functionality including analytics and personalization. By using this website, you automatically accept that we use cookies. 
            </p>
            <div class="ml-auto">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light mr-3" id="btnDeny">
                    Deny
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="btnAccept">
                    Accept
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {   
    document.cookie = name +'=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}

function cookieConsent() {
    if (!getCookie('allowCookies')) {
        $('.toast').toast('show')
    }
}

$('#btnDeny').click(()=>{
    eraseCookie('allowCookies')
    $('.toast').toast('hide')
})

$('#btnAccept').click(()=>{
    setCookie('allowCookies','1',7)
    $('.toast').toast('hide')
})

// load
cookieConsent()
```

[Bootstrap cookie consent demo](https://codeply.com/p/azCmarhM9X/bootstrap-cookie-alert)

Answer (score 0):

```
function ExpireCookie(minutes) {
  var date = new Date();
  var m = minutes;
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + (m * 60 * 1000));
  $.cookie("cookie", "value", { expires: date });
}
```

Call this function in your onClick event. Put the total minutes inside the constructor ( ).

```
ExpireCookie(**ADD MINUTES THAT TOTAL WEEK HERE**);
```

Comment: Ok now i become a failure...
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
              
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nighteyes/fy0w1vLc/

And when i put a number i become the message:
example.html:27 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Comment: @PatrickDierig - It's hard for me to know why the cookie isn't being set! Maybe you should look into using `php`. I know for a fact that you can create cookies on button clicks and have them expire whenever ( If not ever ).

Answer (score 0):

Cookies Notification Popup In Bootstrap 5:
[image]

Cookies Notification is one type of popup that comes in a website or web page to visit for the first time on a website. So here we made an awesome user interface of Cookies Notification Popup In Bootstrap 5 with CSS3.

[demo](https://w3hubs.com/cookies-notification-popup-in-bootstrap-5/)